# CSS Flex Box - Is there a way to auto align center using ::Before ::After so you can add in content

Tags: css, flexbox, gradient

This is the first time I’m wading into using CSS Flexbox instead of floats and for that matter, my CSS is a little rusty. I was wondering if there was a way of mimicking `margin: 0 auto` with a flexbox.

I know that `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: center;` will work normally, but in my case I have an 800px nav section that I always want to be in the center of the browser window (which would be easy using `align-items: center`).

The issue is that I have a background gradient after my nav section that I want to display while keeping the nav centered on the screen. I’ve tried variations of the CSS below but can only get the second code block to work.

```html
nav {
    flex: 0 0 55em;
    height: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url("/images/assets/gradientRL.png");
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

nav::before, nav::after {
    content: "";
    flex: 1 1;
}

nav::after{
background-image: url("/images/assets/gradientLR.png");
background-position: left;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Below works using two divs setting the font color to transparent, but I’m hoping for a better solution. Thanks in advance - CES

```css
nav:first-of-type {
  flex: 0 0 55em;
  height: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  background-image: url("/images/assets/gradientRL.png");
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.one,
.two {
  flex: 1 1;
  color: transparent;
}

.two {
  background-image: url("/images/assets/gradientLR.png");
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<header role="banner">
  <div class="one">x</div>
  <nav class="nav">
    hello
  </nav>
  <div class="two">x</div>
</header>
```

Comment: can you use full path for image, so we can see the gradient ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pseudo elements on the `header` instead of the extra `div` to accomplish that.

Here I made the `header` a flex row container and gave the pseudo `flex: 1`.

This will make the pseudo share the space left equal and push the `nav` to the middle.

Stack snippet

```css
nav {
  width: 100px;
  background: lightgray;
}
header {
  display: flex;
}
header::before, header::after {
  content: ' ';
  flex: 1;
}
header::after {
  background-image: url("http://images.evansante.com/grides/gradientLR.png");
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<header role="banner">
  <nav class="nav">
    hello
  </nav>
</header>
```

---

Do note, you can keep your `div`'s, w/o the need of any tricks with transparent fonts.

Stack snippet

```css
nav {
  width: 100px;
  background: lightgray;
}
header {
  display: flex;
}
header div:first-child, header div:last-child {
  flex: 1;
}
header div:last-child {
  background-image: url("http://images.evansante.com/grides/gradientLR.png");
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<header role="banner">
  <div></div>
  <nav class="nav">
    hello
  </nav>
  <div></div>
</header>
```

Comment: LGSon Thank You... But i'm a little confused why would you put the ::before  ::after on the parent header and not on the nav it's self?

Comment: @CES You can of course use pseudo on the `nav`, like this [http://jsfiddle.net/fbqq7540/](http://jsfiddle.net/fbqq7540/), though since you one way or the other want to treat the centered element explicit, it still need to be wrapped, hence I used the `header`. Do note, pseudo elements are _children_ of the element they are rendered on, not as siblings, as in this sample of my given answer's code, [http://jsfiddle.net/0oz3bomp/](http://jsfiddle.net/0oz3bomp/). So to make them flex items together with the `nav`, they need to be children of the `header`, just like the `div` are in sample 2.